# PHP, stdout from shell_exec

Tags: php, bash, webserver

I am developing a script that requires remote calls to another server. I call my script by executing:

```
(host server) shell_exec("php /dir/script/script.php > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &");
```

Which in turn executes

```
(host server) ssh2_exec($con, "php /remote/server/dir/script.php");
```

My script, "script.php" uses the standard out buffer to return its values (as it executes shell commands) and then it catches the standard out, reads it back in and then performs some work on the data.

My problem is that when I run the script.php locally on the remote server it works, because it can catches the standard out, however remotely running the script it fails because the output is not recorded.

How can I capture the output from the remote script, on the remote server, to allow my script.php to execute.

Thanks for the help!

EDIT:

My code that executes the ssh2_exec is as follows:

```
$stream = ssh2_exec($con, "php /remote/server/dir/script.php" );
stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
$stream_out = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDIO);
echo stream_get_contents($stream_out);
```

Comment: How did you process the script output from `ssh2_exec`? It did not really help understanding where your problem is, that you called both scripts `script.php`. Maybe you should clarify that...

Comment: The complete ssh2_exec script portion is:
[code]
        $stream = ssh2_exec($con, "php /remote/server/dir/script.php" );
  stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
  $stream_out = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDIO);
  echo stream_get_contents($stream_out);
[/code]

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code this seems abstract.  But it doesn't seem that either script actually is returning a value.  So you using your snippets I can recommend this:

**Server1:**

```
<?php
    shell_exec("php /dir/script/script.php > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &");
?>
```

**Server2:**

```
<?php
    return shell_exec("php /dir/script/script.php");
?>
```

Note that the second script returns a value & that I also removed the `> /dev/null 2>/dev/null &` from the second script since all that does is prevent output from the proceeding inline command.

Hope this helps.  If not, please clarify what you are doing with less abstract—and more concrete—examples.

Comment: If this explains it better,

Server 1: runs shell_exec("php /dir/script/script.php > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &");
which then runs ssh2_exec($con, "php /dir/script/script.php" );
Server2: As commanded by Server 1 runs "php /dir/script/script.php"

however when server 2 runs the script, the output from the script.php is not picked up (its lost), ie if script.php runs "sell_exec(ping google.com)", it cannot read the output from its own shell_exec.

Does that make it more clear?

I really do appreciate the help!

Comment: I've updated the topic, perhaps it will provide more clarification?

Answer (score 0):

Use `stream_get_contents()` to get what the command outputs.

If you're trying to do some large processing you may instead want to use something like a messaging queue (amqp, rabbitmq) or something like gearman.